# C# Print Monitor Service

Tags: c#, service, printing

I am trying to write a **service** that monitors the printers queue in C# that sends the information of a current print job (Document name, pages printed, paper media size) to an another application possibly that will then popup (like the Windows Msg "document has been sent to printer"). I am not sure if there is any examples or if anybody knows what classes are best used, being the printers are on a Windows printer server.

Thanks,

[How do I retrieve a list or number of jobs from a printer queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593448/how-do-i-retrieve-a-list-or-number-of-jobs-from-a-printer-queue) also doesn't completely match what I am asking, so read before marking as duplicate which it isn't.

Comment: Your question has a number of problems, including that you're asking how to do a "big thing". It's not that you tried to write something and asked how to make the next step.
That's why I ask: How is you question different from the duplicate? If you know how to write a service, I think you can use the info given there. If there's a difference, please give more (any) details about what's different, why, and what you tried so far. Only then can this question add some value for somebody else searching this website for clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the System.Printing.PrintQueue class and the System.Printing.LocalPrintServer class - especially the GetDefaultPrintQueue method on the LocalPrintServer class