# How to get printer information using C# on the .NET framework 4.7

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I'm working on a somehow a small application in Winforms where I can see the printers I have on my application with detailed information similar the the configuration site of the printers. Every block of code I find online is either giving me `false` when getting bool variables like this:

```
MachineName = "My Machine Name";
LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
localPrintServer.Refresh();
PrintQueue pq = new PrintQueue(localPrintServer, MachineName.Trim());
pq.Refresh();
MessageBox.Show(pq.IsPrinting.ToString());
```

or I'm getting the "Win32 Access Denied" error like when using:

```
using (var ps = new PrintServer())
{
    using (var pq = new PrintQueue(ps, MachineName, PrintSystemDesiredAccess.UsePrinter))
    {
        foreach (var job in pq.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
    }
}
```

I'm out of ideas, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this answer any use? Seems very similar to what you have but it uses a `PrinterName` to find a specific print queue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593448/how-do-i-retrieve-a-list-or-number-of-jobs-from-a-printer-queue

Comment: its the same but in another way, the "MachineName" in my code is a string variable containg the PrinterName